# Generating download link in djano

Tags: django, download

I have referred to multiple django question regarding file download and this was the solution suggested.

```
{% for task in tasks %}
            <tr><td><strong> name {{task.name}}</strong></td>           
            <td><strong> date {{task.date_created}}</strong></td>
            <td><strong> status  {{task.status}}</strong></td>
            <td><strong> id {{task.id}}</strong></td>
            <td><strong> input file {{task.input_file_path}}<td>
            <td><a href="{{task.output_file_path}}" download>output file</td></tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

The solution suggested is `<a href="{{task.output_file_path}}" download>` However, when i check my django request. It shows up this in console. `GET /adv_filters/check/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/download/input_files/input_files/input_files/input_files/input_files/task4 HTTP/1.1" 200 2524`

For testing purposes. I have set the location of the output file to be the location of the input file.

My relevant **`views.py`**

```
document.input_file_path = 'input_files/' + document.name
            document.output_file_path = 'input_files/' + document.name
```

Models.py

```
doc = models.FileField(upload_to='input_files')
```

Is there anymore information i would need.

Comment: Could you please share your media setting from settings.py

Comment: I do not have any specific setting for it

Comment: I think that's the problem. You need to setup your media files location and media URL.

Comment: I do have it in my models.py

Comment: Not in models.py. That should be setup in settings.py

Comment: @RahulReddyVemireddy I tried and it still didnt work

Answer (score 1):

I guess simply putting file link(i.e. which I am assuming `{{task.output_file_path}}` is) should work.

```
<td><a href="{{task.output_file_path}}"</a> Download output file</td>
```